# How much of MuscleTech Anabolic Halo's causes the creatine effect?

Tags: supplements, creatine

I've started using MuscleTech's Anabolic Halo about a couple of weeks ago and I've gotten really big with it. Some body parts have grown by over an inch and 8 pounds. One of the ingredients it includes is Creatine Monohydrate and wondering how much of the gains are water and how much is muscle.  Is there a way to tell?

BTW, I had been experimenting with Creatine Monohydrate alone a couple of months ago with the same results, although never gained more than 5 pounds and only my legs had gotten bigger.  Plus after I stopped using it lost the increased size fairly quickly.

Let me know if you need more info.

BTW, Some of the reviews I have read suggest there is actual muscle gain and not water gain.  So not really sure what to think.

[MuscleTech Anabolic Halo](http://www.muscletech.com/products/anabolichalo/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular supplement, but I can answer your question of figuring out how much is muscle and how much is water.  You can go to a professional and have them measure your lean, fat, and water weights by conductivity through your body, but that is relatively expensive and time consuming.  Doing it at home basically requires that you weigh yourself often and get a handle on your median weight.

The reason I say 'median weight' is because you can gain or lose as many as 5 pounds a day just in water weight, depending on how much you drink, how hard you work, and even just how dry the environment around you is.   It's impossible to properly control.  So weigh yourself 3 times a day for a few days, and get the median of those weights.  This will give you a figure that is reasonably close to your 'true' weight by only using a common scale.  Any changes of more than a few pounds are going to almost certainly indicate muscle or fat growth - in your case, I'd say it's a safe guess that most of the difference would be muscle.